# How can I include js files correspondes to render files in laravel blade template?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my laravel app I have `app.blade.php` with following code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('jquery.min.js') }}" ></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bootstrap.min.js') }}" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have several pages such as `page1`, `page2` etc and each page is rendering as `page1.blade.php` etc and these pages has separate javascript files like `page1.js`, `page2.js`.

`page1.js` should be included with `page1.blade.php` only and same for `page2.js` also. How can I include js files for the corresponding blade files?

My `page1.blade.php` is

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<section class="content-header">
  <h1>
    Page 1
  </h1>

</section>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @stack method that comes after 5.1 versions.
For Details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks

Answer (score 5):

`app.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <script src="{{ asset('jquery.min.js') }}" ></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('bootstrap.min.js') }}" ></script>
        @yield('script')
    </body>
</html>
```

and `page1.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<section class="content-header">
  <h1>
    Page 1
  </h1>

</section>
@endsection

@section('script')
  <script src="{{ asset('page1.js') }}" ></script>
@endsection
```